# Inserting a record a number of times equal to a column value

Tags: php, mysql, db2

I have a query where I'm selecting records from DB2 database and storing the values in an array:

```
$orderIdsStr = "'" . implode("', '", $order_ids) . "'";
//SELECT FROM DB2 WITH THE ORDER NUMBERS FIRST
$query = "SELECT invnoc as INVOICE,
                 cstnoc AS DEALER,
                 framec AS FRAME,
                 covr1c AS COVER,
                 colr1c AS COLOR ,
                 extd2d AS SHIPDATE,
                 orqtyc AS QUANTITY
          FROM GPORPCFL
          WHERE invnoc IN ({$orderIdsStr})
          GROUP BY invnoc,cstnoc, slsnoc, orqtyc, framec, covr1c,colr1c, extd2d
          ORDER BY invnoc asc
          LIMIT 35";


$Db2ShipRslt = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $query);
if ( $Db2ShipRslt === false ) {
     exit (odbc_errormsg($DB2Conn));
}


//Process the results
$Db2ShipArr = array();
while($db2ShipRow = odbc_fetch_array($Db2ShipRslt)){
{
    //Output the record
    print_r($db2ShipRow);    /*This prints the correct Rows*/
    //Append record to results array
    $Db2ShipArr[] = $db2ShipRow;
}
```

And this works, pulling correct records and storing them properly.

I also have an insert that works properly (it inserts the exact number of records and appropriate values). BUt I'm wondering how I can apply a certain condition to the insert and I've never  had to do this.

My select grabs a value called `orqtyc` as alias `QUANTITY` and I insert those values to my mysql `placements_new` table in a column called `locations`. This is appropriate but I'd also like to be able to have it insert each record  a number of times equal to that value.

Basically `if row is < :QUANTITY , keep inserting until the record is inserted n times, n being :QUANTITY value`. So if `:QUANTITY` = 3, that same record should be inserted 3 times. Technically there would be duplicates but this way each row has it's own set of dates.

Again, the select/insert both work and the arrays return what I need. All I need some help with is how to make the insert write the number of rows = to the quantity value.

Here's the other part where the insert takes place:

```
foreach($Db2ShipArr as $Db2Ship){

    /*THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA*/

        if($rows < :QUANTITY, INSERT n = :QUANTITY){
        //INSERT # of records equal to QUANTITY
            $stmt = $PDO->prepare("
                INSERT IGNORE INTO placements_new (sku_id, group_id, dealer_id, start_date, expire_date, locations, order_num)
                 SELECT 
                 id, 
                 sku_group_id, 
                 :DEALER, 
                 DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 7 DAY) as start_date,
                 DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY) as expire_date, 
                 :QUANTITY,
                 :INVOICE  
                 FROM skus s
                 WHERE  s.frame=:FRAME AND s.cover1=:COVER AND s.color1=:COLOR 
            ");


        $PDO->beginTransaction();
        $i = 0;
        while($db2row = odbc_fetch_array($Db2ShipRslt)) {


            if(++$i % 1000 == 0) {
                $PDO->commit();
                $PDO->beginTransaction();
            }
            $stmt->execute($db2row);
        }
        $PDO->commit();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's the fiddle I made. so in this fiddle the record I've inserted for GPORPCFL would, through the php logic/looop, be inserted into placements_new 3 times, since 3 is the value of `orqtyc`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26b921

Comment: Performance benefits aside, in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is likely to lead to problems further down the road.

Comment: So for the problem I'm having, would you recommend removing it altogether?

Comment: I would remove it in all situations.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the advice. I'll try to get out of the habit of using them

Comment: **WARNING**: This DB2 code appears to be full of SQL injection bugs. Make sure any and all data is properly escaped and use *prepared statements with placeholder values* whenever possible, like your PDO code does. It's worth noting that PDO [supports DB2](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.php) so you can use the same interface for both MySQL and DB2.

Comment: Thank you @tadman, I wasn't aware PDO had a DB2 support as well until last night and I hadn't made those changes yet, but rest assured I am refactoring the code to use PDO across the board. I'm still having the issue above, but at least my connections will be secure

Comment: @tadman would I be better off to create a PDO statement for my 3 general select queries, and then just create looped logic that inherit the variables from them? So the queries are set at the top of the script with PDO, then I can just have sections that perform each check and insert/update that I need?

Comment: I think going PDO all the way here would make it a lot more consistent and easier to fix.

Comment: Ok I'm going to go with that. I've never used it very heavily but I know how important it is to do so. I'm going to start out by creating PDO connections and queries. Then I think I might can create variables from the values I need out of those queries and just create loops for each process I need to work through using those variables